# ActivityNotFoundException for unknown reasons

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I'm starting to learn Xamarin, and I'm stuck in this problem. There is an exception thrown

> Android.Content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=Chris...
> https://www.removeddit.com/r/greentext/comments/a9rwbb/anon_goes_to_christmas_dinner/eclyp8c

## Background: I'm developing a small personal project that opens removeddit in a browser automatically from my phone through reddit.

The issue is it throws the exception when I run the code below. That probably would have been my mistake and I haven't googled enough. But surprisingly when I copy-paste and override the output link with the URI produced by the three lines of code in pre-processing, as observed in the debug line, the browser opens up with the right webpage.

Current Code that doesn't work:

```
//Let's call it pre-processing
string outputLink = inputLink.Substring(inputLink.LastIndexOf(' '));
outputLink = outputLink.Replace("reddit", "removeddit");
outputLink = outputLink.Trim();
                
Log.Info("DebugTag", outputLink);

Uri uri = Uri.Parse(outputLink);
var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, uri);
StartActivity(intent);
```

Replacement code that makes it work in place of pre-processing:

```
string outputLink = "https://www.removeddit.com/r/greentext/comments/a9rwbb/anon_goes_to_christmas_dinner/eclyp8c"
```

I absolutely have no idea what the mistake might be and I'm completely baffled.

EDIT: Added exception I'm observing.

Comment: What exactly do you plan on accomplishing using this code?

Comment: @G.hakim I intend to open the newly generated link to the removeddit website (after manipulating input string) in the preferred browser.

Comment: so basically you want to open a URL on the browser?

Comment: @G.hakim Yes. And it appears to work when instantiated in the code manually, but doesn't when generated by the pre-process. The URL produced is a valid one, and can be checked by the one include in the exception thrown.

Comment: Can you add the exception details as that might help

Comment: @G.hakim I have added a new exception that's being thrown out recently. The previous one is also seen on top.

Comment: could you show your complete pre-processing code?

Comment: @LeoZhu Previously, I didn't format the code properly. I have formatted it properly so it's visible.